# How to set up VSTS 2013 to complete pull request by rebasing to master instead of merge?

Tags: git, azure-devops

Is there a way to set up VSTS 2013 web portal to rebase to master while accepting and completing pull request instead of merging to master?

Comment: No (from what I know of)

Answer (score 1):

It should become available in 2019 Q1 according to the [Features Timeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/), so for Azure DevOps Server 2019 (not TFS 2013), it should be in a future Update 1.0.